# How can I test apt-get updates on a test box before deploying to production?

Tags: apt, testing, update, synchronization

I would like to schedule updates on my ubuntu servers, but would like to test the updates first on a test server.  I'd like to run all updates on the test box at the beginning of a development cycle, giving QA time to test our code changes + ubuntu package updates.  So, my question is, how do I ensure that I get the same package versions when go do an apt-get upgrade on my production boxes, given that it may be a week or two later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a local Ubuntu repository and update your systems from that.  Then you can only update the repository when you want to, and you'll know your production boxes will get the same code as development.

Check out tools such as [apt-mirror](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/apt-mirror), and [apt-cacher](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/apt-cacher).

Comment: looks good, I'll look into how to implement these... can u point me in the direction of a good howto?

Comment: Never done it, but a random google search turns up http://www.howtoforge.com/local_debian_ubuntu_mirror and http://popey.com/blog/2006/10/24/Creating_an_Ubuntu_repository_mirror_with_apt-mirror/

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure this is by running your own apt mirror. This way you can do your test update from the same mirror where you know your production systems will be doing the update.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply; accepted EightBit's answer because he included links :)